# Dynamic grouping in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

So I have these 3 table/views in my database.

```
Table
id
template

View1 // the ids in this view have a corresponding id in table if template = 1
id
type1

View2 // the ids in this view have a corresponding id in table if template = 2
id
type2
```

So in my report, I want to select all the ids... and then group by template, and then group by type. I can do this for one View at a time by setting up the group to be either View1.type1 or View2.type2. But, I want it to group by View1.type1 if template is 1 and then I want it to group by View2.type2 if the template is 2.

So I made a forumla called type, and changed the group to that formula.. So I am first grouping by template, and then by type (my formula). If I set the formula for type as below:

```
formula = {View1.type1}
```

Then it works as expected and I see the correct grouping. It also works if I only do it for View2.type2.

However, when I do this:

```
if {Table.template} = 1
    formula = {View1.type1}
else
    formula = {View2.type2}
```

This returns no data for my grouping. Even if I do this:

```
if 1 = 1
    formula = {View1.type1}
else
    formula = {View2.type2}
```

This also returns no data. How is dynamic grouping supposed to work? I am missing something? I guess at the worst case I can make another view in my database or even use subreports... but I was hoping to have it work like this... I greatly appreciate the help guys!...

UPDATE:
So I can do formulas such as this one:

```
if {View1.type1} = "" then
    formula = "[Undefined]"
else 
    formula = {View1.type1}
end if
```

It looks like I only have issues when I try to use a formula with the 2 views...

Comment: +1 for trying to work this out on your own :)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, "formula = " is unnecessary in crystal syntax. Try removing that and see what happens.

Comment: "formula = " is part of the Basic syntax... I get the same result when I use crystal syntax

Comment: I guess those views are not linked in the Database Expert? Crystal Reports cannot work the way you want when using unlinked tables/views.